# My glass(diamond) is reflecting nature, not transparent

Tags: glass

I am new to Blender 2.8.

I try to make a diamond, so I used glass BSDF.
But it shows me nature on the surface like metal, not showing the other side or some shiny refraction.
Its metallic is 0.

What should I change to look like a diamond?

[image]

Comment: Is the "Screen Space Reflections" option from the render properties checked on?

Comment: change renderer to "Cycles Renderer" and hit "Z" key and go to Rendered Mode. And also check if your IOR value is of Diamond 2.418 you can check it here https://pixelandpoly.com/ior.html

Answer (score 1):

You are using a glossy shader, which acts like metal.  I suggest using a glossy shader added to a refraction shader, it provides pretty good results.  [image: Here's an image of the nodes]

Comment: thank you! It shows now the other side through it. But it shows me still nature.... I can't find still how to solve this anywhere..

Comment: That's because you're in the look dev view.  The look dev view has a default environment texture.

Comment: Yeah! I think he's in dev/MaterialPreview Mode.

Answer (score 0):

The viewport shading is set to "Look Dev" you need to change this to "Rendered" if you want it to look as it would appear when rendered.

[image]

Also the index of refraction for diamond is 2.417 ... you have it set to 10.00 (way above the known maximum of ~4.05 for Germanium).

Comment: Thank you! I tried but it only turns into a black object... and when I keep the third one, still it is nature.. haha I wanted it to be look like real diamond when it is rendered, but I don't find any solution still :( but thank you very much though!

Comment: I was using cycles render, but you should look at this question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154931/how-to-look-like-real-diamondrender-now-seeing-an-environment